# Why do i get different value when i use gmp_init() in PHP , compared with bigint() in Js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, gmp, bigint

please i'm stuck with this problem for 2 days .

when i use bigint() in Javascript , and gmp_init() in php i get the same output , but just if the input less than 13 chiffre after 0x.

whene i use **BigInt()** Function in ***javascript*** , with input more than 13 chiffre :

> BigInt(0x400000000328923310a4110a1044210210a4190810c431061064190610a51102)

i get this output:

> **2894802230966167**8603302180203248060948583747460481826940765458987714326036480n

and whene i used **gmp_init()** in ***php*** with the same input i get another output

> gmp_init(0x400000000328923310a4110a1044210210a4190810c431061064190610a51102)

i get this output:  (but its different just after first 16 Chiffre)

> **2894802230966167**5709966313502906776944636064151207602940776381119786782101762

My goal is get the same result of **BigInt()** in js using PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you're initialising your Javascript BigInt with an integer in hexadecimal format. The number exceeds Javascript's maximum value, so the stored value is incorrect.

If you initialise your BigInt with a string, or suffix your number with the BigInt suffix of `n` then you get the same value as PHP returns.

```js
// Initialise with integer in hex format (wrong!)
let a = BigInt(0x400000000328923310a4110a1044210210a4190810c431061064190610a51102);
console.log(a.toString(10));

// Initialise with hex integer in BigInt format
let b = BigInt(0x400000000328923310a4110a1044210210a4190810c431061064190610a51102n);
console.log(b.toString(10));

// Initialise with hex integer as string
let c = BigInt('0x400000000328923310a4110a1044210210a4190810c431061064190610a51102');
console.log(c.toString(10));
```

Output

```
28948022309661678603302180203248060948583747460481826940765458987714326036480
28948022309661675709966313502906776944636064151207602940776381119786782101762
28948022309661675709966313502906776944636064151207602940776381119786782101762
```

Comment: Thank u so much , what you say is totaly make since , now i understand why i get different Output. But ...

Comment: The problem now , is there any way in php to use gmp_init() with param "integer in hex format" because when i write the below code :

Comment: `$a = 0x400000000328923310a4110a1044210210a4190810c431061064190610a51102;     
return (gmp_init($a));`

Comment: **i got this Error :** 

ErrorException
gmp_init(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type

Comment: That number is larger than the maximum integer value natively  supported by any version of PHP. That is why you need GMP. That code makes no sense. For a number that large you need to initialise your GMP object with a string.

Comment: Thanks again , yes i undersant what you say , so using GMP how can i get  the result like the first output you get in your code.

Comment: ok , i figured out that for two days i'm searching for a worng value , and the correct value i already get it yesterday hhhhhh , please provide me with your email , i will donate after selling the solution i'm working on , i can't donate now i'm still studying hhhhh, Thank a lot

Comment: i got the links : https://www.pragmanotdogma.com/buy-me-a-coffee

Thanks